# NginxでGETするファイルのルーティングに関して

Tags: php, nginx

初めて質問をさせていただきます。
ただいまNGINXに簡易APIの実装をしています。
やりたいことなのですが、ttp://localhost/api/api.phpではなく
ttp://localhost/api/へのアクセスでやりたいです。

そのためNginxの設定は

```
     location /api/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/api/;
        index api.php;
    }
```

のようにしました。

そしてアクセスしてみたところ、ttp://localhost/api/は予想通りの結果を得られましたが
ttp://localhost/api?user=testのようにGETの値をつけてもttp://localhost/api/に飛ばされてしまいgetの値は無視される結果となってしまいました。

伝えるのが苦手で申し訳ないのですが、どうかご教示ください。